# Ansible: ignoring erros in include tasks

Tags: error-handling, ansible

I have in my yml include to a certain yml can I add ignore_erors like:

```
include: ../test.tml
ignore_errors: yes
```

or only in the playbook I included itself
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Playbook keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords) can be applied to 4 objects: a play, role, block, task. *ignore_errors* can be applied to all of them.

---

**Correct syntax**

In your example, *include* is a task. The correct syntax is

```yaml
- include: ../test.yml
  ignore_errors: yes
```

---

**Include is deprecated**

Quoting from [include - Include a play or task list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/include_module.html#include-include-a-play-or-task-list)

> The include action was too confusing, dealing with both plays and tasks, being both dynamic and static. This module will be removed in version 2.8. As alternatives use include_tasks, import_playbook, import_tasks.